# JNI: Access to 'keySet' method with android.os.Bundle instance

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I am attempting to get a list of the keys used in the extra bundle, coming from the Intent, when launching an activity. The extra bundle is being returned from the intent, but when I attempt to get the set of keys, the `jmethodID` is coming back null:

```
JNIEnv* jni = ...;
jobject extraBundle = ...; // from 'Intent.getExtras()'
jclass  bundleClass = jni->GetObjectClass(extraBundle);
jmethodID keySetMethod = jni->GetMethodID(bundleClass, "keySet", "()Ljava/util/Set"); // keySetMethod == nullptr
```

The `keySet` method comes from `android.os.BaseBundle`, which `android.os.Bundle` derives from. I have verified the signatures using `java -s android.os.BaseBundle`. I've tried using `jni->FindClass("android/os/BaseBundle")`, and using that as the `jclass`, but with the same results.

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class signature is incorrect.
When you specify an object, you must use this format `Lobject;`.

```
jmethodID keySetMethod = jni->GetMethodID(bundleClass, "keySet", "(V)Ljava/util/Set;");
```